# Does altering a session invalidate Package States in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a package that gets invalidated on a regular basis and found this in the code:

```
ALTER SESSION CLOSE  DATABASE LINK;
```

Can this invalidate package states?  Though I can't seem to replicate it.

```
create or replace package body invalid_package_state_test is

procedure test is
 TEMP VARCHAR2(1) := NULL;

begin
 SELECT 'Y' INTO TEMP FROM dual@dw;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Testing');


     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   'ALTER SESSION CLOSE  DATABASE LINK DW';
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBLink Not Open');
end test;
end invalid_package_state_test;
```

Also, can someone explain when does one need the `ALTER SESSION CLOSE  DATABASE LINK;`?

Comment: Only reason I can see is if the package references the db link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1. Does closing a database link invalidate the package?**

Not sure, but if so I suspect it'll be because of the "`SELECT FROM dual@dw`", not because of the `ALTER`. What happens if you hide `dual@dw` behind a local view? Does the db link get created/dropped from time to time or is it created just once?

**Q2. Why close a database link?**

From the documentation:

> **Closing Database Links**
>
> If you access a
>   database link in a session, then the
>   link remains open until you close the
>   session. A link is open in the sense
>   that a process is active on each of
>   the remote databases accessed through
>   the link. This situation has the
>   following consequences:
>
> If 20 users open sessions and access
>   the same public link in a local
>   database, then 20 database link
>   connections are open.
>
> If 20 users open sessions and each
>   user accesses a private link, then 20
>   database link connections are open.
>
> If one user starts a session and
>   accesses 20 different links, then 20
>   database link connections are open.
>
> After you close a session, the links
>   that were active in the session are
>   automatically closed. You may have
>   occasion to close the link manually.
>   For example, close links when:
>
> The network connection established by
>   a link is used infrequently in an
>   application.
>
> The user session must be terminated.
>
> If you want to close a link, issue the
>   following statement, where linkname
>   refers to the name of the link:
>
> ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK
>   linkname;
>
> Note that this statement only closes
>   the links that are active in your
>   current session.

[Source: Oracle 10gR2 docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/ds_admin.htm#sthref4168)